# Decrease UILabel Font size to exact point using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, cgaffinetransform

I have a `UITableView` and a `UINavigationBar` with its custom title label. I want to decrease the title label font size on scroll down and increase it on scroll up.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17)
}
```

Here I set the font size for my label.

And then, I transform the font size like so

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let scale = min(max(1.0 - offset / 200.0, 0.0), 1.0)
    myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
}
```

The problem is, the minimum point is set to 0 this way, but I want my label to decrease to 11 points, etc.

Can anyone help me edit my code?

Answer (score 1):

calculate the final scale with this formula

```
let defualtFontSize = 17.0
let minFontSize = 11.0
let finalFontSize = CGFloat(minFontSize / defualtFontSize)
```

then use finalFontSize here

```
let scale = min(max(1.0 - offset / 200.0, finalFontSize), 1.0)
```

complete code

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


    let defualtFontSize = 17.0
    let minFontSize = 11.0
    let finalFontSize = CGFloat(minFontSize / defualtFontSize)

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let scale = min(max(1.0 - offset / 200.0, finalFontSize), 1.0)
    myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
}
```

but write the calculation somewhere out of scrollViewDidScroll, avoiding CPU Usage.